# How to get list of li in repeater that contains many ul and li

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater that loads my categories and products and my repeater code is:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptCategories">
<ItemTemplate>
<#% Eval("CategoryName") %>
<ul>
<li>
<#% Eval("ProductName") %>
</li>
</ul>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I bind repeater with inner join from 2 tables and user can drag items from a tree view to this repeater and drop it in ul tags, at the end I have a button for saving new items to database and I need to get list of each li tags in ul tags, my question is how can I get the list of lis in ul tags?

Comment: You should consider moving the `<ul>` tags outside of the `<ItemTemplate>` -- either by moving the start and end `ul` tags to `<HeaderTemplate>` and `<FooterTemplate>` respectively, or by moving them outside of the repeater specification altogether.

Comment: I can not, because each ul is my category and each category has products, like a menu that parent nodes show categories and child nodes show category products.

Comment: Now i dynamically add repeater for each category and i have ul tag outside of repeater, so tell me how can i get li list that are in repeater @DavidTansey